# Create a DE field that has GUID/NewId as its Default value

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder, email-studio

I am trying to add a field to existing DEs that has a non-nullable Default value that generates a random ID, similar to what the GUID() and NewId() functions do but within the Email Studio Data Extensions/Contact Builder UI. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, but there are ways of doing it, using e.g.:

**SQL:**

```sql
SELECT
  NEWID() as id
  EmailAddress,
  GETDATE() as Created
FROM
  SourceDE
```

**AmpScript:**

```ampscript
%%[
var @emailAddress, @id, @rowsAdded, @insertDate

set @id = GUID()
set @emailAddress = AttributeValue("emailaddr")
set @insertDate = Now(1)

set @rowsAdded = insertData("Members","EmailAddress", @emailAddress, "Id", @id, "Created", @insertDate)
]%%
```

**SSJS:**

```javascript
<script runat="server">
var emailAddress = Platform.Variable.GetAttributeValue("emailaddr");
var insertDate = new Date();
var id = Platform.Function.GUID();

var rows = Platform.Function.InsertData("Members",["EmailAddress","InsertDate","Id"],[emailAddress,insertDate,id]);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Lukas 

Thanks for the quick and useful response! 

So just to clarify, there is no way to have a unique value generated in a DE field without having to use SQL, SSJS & AMPscript?

Comment: This is correct, except of utilising _CustomObjectKey, as described by Jonas

Comment: Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use those placeholders on the UI, but you already have a field in every DE automatically that might possibly be used to the same effect:

The hidden DE field `_CustomObjectKey` is basically a unique rowkey which you can leverage in scripts and sql. It is not random; It's just a number, not in GUID format.

Comment: And you did it again :-)

Comment: Hi Jonas

Thanks for this Insight! Do you know if this hidden field _CustomObjectKey can display its values by Default or does this need to be done via SQL, SSJS or AMPscript?

Comment: It's hidden, i.e. you will never see it on the UI directly.
You CAN expose it into some other data extension like `SELECT _CustomObjectKey as myfieldName FROM whatever`, or overwrite the data extension itself, but I wouldn't recommend that just like that.

Comment: I would like to give one cent on this, if you are planning to use the _customobjectkey extensively in SQLs, there are chances that it will fail abruptly sometimes without any definite error. So, be cautious of this field.

Comment: Interesting. According to where it's mentioned in the documentation, it is an index and should be highly performant in lookups etc ("An index on the Boolean and _CustomObjectKey columns to allow for an efficient lookup of claimed rows"); https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/claimrowvalue.htm

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, take care